# application wide classes for codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, global-scope

I'm starting to use codeigniter for the first time and starting to plan out the coding structure.

I have a number of 'objects' which are referenced on a regular basis throughout the applications: user, article, photo, comment, forum topic, etc. These objects will do common functions like get/set specific details about a user, article, photo, comment, topic etc. This stuff is generally referenced on pretty much every controller at one point or another.

Where is the correct/best practice way to store these and how?

Comment: They should typically be in your libraries, or models folders. Then again I can't say for sure since I don't know really what these objects are meant to do. If you post more info about each then it would be easier.

Comment: See http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/creating_libraries.html and http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/models.html

Answer (score -2, accepted):

That's exactly how MVC works...

Sounds like you'd create models/libraries for each of your business objects and then either use the config->autoload to include them or load them in your core controller class (application/core/MY_Controller).

Comment: Thanks, I just wanted to be sure that theres are mean't to be models and not something else.

Comment: this has nothing to do with "how mvc works".

Comment: separation of data interaction from application instructions and UI? That's not 'how MVC works'? News to me...I thought that was the whole point of the MVC pattern.

Answer (score -1):

In general i would suggest building out your methods in the controller, and then refactor and push the methods to the model. Then refactor within your models. The controller says - Do This and waves its hand like a commander. it does not say how to do it, the 'how' is in the model.

Another suggestion I'm just learning about - is to design and build out the application from the point of view of the User Role - like Admin, Purchaser, Editor, etc. Don't put the tools that are used like CRUD in the center of the app. The app should be driven by what the user needs to do. 'Uncle Bob' Martin has a great quote - if you ask an architect to show you a design for a house, they dont come back with a list of tools like hammer, saw, and tape measure. And the architectural design is not cluttered with a bunch of implementation details. the blueprint - or your object design -  is specific only for what is necessary.